# Insert negative number - ORA-01722

Tags: java, string, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdbctemplate

I'm using jdbcTemplate to insert into DataBase Oracle some data. Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid Number
```

First of all, I convert the string to double:

```
Number number = nmFormat.parse(record[8]);
double doubleVLBalance = number.doubleValue();
```

And After :

```
 String sqlSettlementBalance = "INSERT INTO STARR4.TBSETR_SETTLEMENT_BALANCE"+
                "(DT_MOVEMENT,NU_CUSTOMER_REF, NU_MOD_CUSTOMER_REF,"+
                "NU_HIERARCHICAL_NODE, CD_ACQUIRER, CD_PRODUCT,"+
                "CD_BALANCE_TYPE, NU_CUSTOMER, VL_BALANCE, NU_CONTROL)"+
                "VALUES ('" ...,'"+doubleVLBalance+"','"+sb.getNuControl()+"')";

jdbcTemplate.update(sqlSettlementBalance);
```

The value of the string record[8] is "-0.34". Any suggestion to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you surround a Number with quotes, it becomes a string. Remove the Quotes.

```
 String sqlSettlementBalance = "INSERT INTO STARR4.TBSETR_SETTLEMENT_BALANCE"+
            "(DT_MOVEMENT,NU_CUSTOMER_REF, NU_MOD_CUSTOMER_REF,"+
            "NU_HIERARCHICAL_NODE, CD_ACQUIRER, CD_PRODUCT,"+
            "CD_BALANCE_TYPE, NU_CUSTOMER, VL_BALANCE, NU_CONTROL)"+
            "VALUES ('" ...,"+doubleVLBalance+",'"+sb.getNuControl()+"')";
```

Answer (score 3):

As mention before you should delete quotes, but I recommend instead of

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlSettlementBalance);
```

using

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlSettlementBalance, Object... args);
```

for example something like this:

```
 String sqlSettlementBalance = "INSERT INTO STARR4.TBSETR_SETTLEMENT_BALANCE"+
            "(DT_MOVEMENT,NU_CUSTOMER_REF, NU_MOD_CUSTOMER_REF,"+
            "NU_HIERARCHICAL_NODE, CD_ACQUIRER, CD_PRODUCT,"+
            "CD_BALANCE_TYPE, NU_CUSTOMER, VL_BALANCE, NU_CONTROL)"+
            "VALUES ('"...,?,'"+sb.getNuControl()+"')";

jdbcTemplate.update(sqlSettlementBalance, doubleVLBalance);
```

Of use PreparedStatement see example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989354/4318868)